# program crashes on calling RmShutdown()

Tags: c, winapi

I'm experiencing a strange issue with the Restart Manager API.

I'm trying to debug a runtime error that is causing my program to crash in the middle of execution.

I have created a logging system that writes a simple log text file during the course of execution. I tried to debug the program, but it doesn't appear in my system, and the program crashes on calling `RmShutdown()`.

This function crashes on specific files, and sometimes it doesn't appear. For example, most times it appears on `C:\Users\Administrator\ntuser.dat.LOG1`.
I know I shouldn't kill a system process, but it's a test when the crash happens. Does killing a process that has a handle of file make my program crash?

What could possibly be wrong here? Why would `RmShutdown()` fail?

```
BOOL KillFileOwner(__in LPCWSTR PathName)
{
    BOOL Result = FALSE;
    DWORD dwSession = 0xFFFFFFFF; // Invalid handle value
    DWORD ret = 0;
    WCHAR szSessionKey[CCH_RM_SESSION_KEY + 1] = { 0 };

    if (RmStartSession(&dwSession, 0, szSessionKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (RmRegisterResources(dwSession, 1, &PathName, 0, NULL, 0, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            DWORD dwReason = 0x0;
            UINT nProcInfoNeeded = 0;
            UINT nProcInfo = 0;
            PRM_PROCESS_INFO ProcessInfo = NULL;
            // RtlSecureZeroMemory(&ProcessInfo, sizeof(ProcessInfo));

            ret = (DWORD)RmGetList(dwSession, &nProcInfoNeeded, &nProcInfo, NULL, &dwReason);
            if (ret != ERROR_MORE_DATA || !nProcInfoNeeded) {

                RmEndSession(dwSession);
                return FALSE;
            }

            ProcessInfo = (PRM_PROCESS_INFO)calloc(nProcInfoNeeded, sizeof(RM_PROCESS_INFO));
            if (!ProcessInfo) {
                RmEndSession(dwSession);
                return FALSE;
            }

            nProcInfo = nProcInfoNeeded;
            ret = (DWORD)RmGetList(dwSession, &nProcInfoNeeded, &nProcInfo, ProcessInfo, &dwReason);
            if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS || !nProcInfoNeeded) {

                free(ProcessInfo);
                RmEndSession(dwSession);
                return FALSE;
            }

            DWORD ProcessId = (DWORD)GetProcessId(GetCurrentProcess());
            if (!ProcessId) {

                free(ProcessInfo);
                RmEndSession(dwSession);
                return FALSE;
            }

            for (UINT i = 0; i < nProcInfo; i++) {

                if (ProcessInfo[i].Process.dwProcessId == ProcessId) {

                    free(ProcessInfo);
                    RmEndSession(dwSession);
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }

            Result = (RmShutdown(dwSession, RmForceShutdown, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS);
            free(ProcessInfo);
        }

        RmEndSession(dwSession);
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Comment: for what use `Rm*` api when the best use `FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation` on file direct

Comment: It has been a long time. Have you solved your problem with @RbMm help？

Comment: @Junjie Zhu - MSFT No I didn't solve the problem yet, I used another method

Comment: Have you seen this code sample? https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/6625e1af4f44263e1842919c729eb72a20d3ffb6/Samples/Win7Samples/winbase/restartmanager/rmfilterapp/RmFilterApp/rmfilterapp.cpp